# Preservation of the Euler-Poincaré characteristics and commutativity of the multiplication in R^d

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fields, duality

While talking about duality for polyhedra and the analogue for polygons (where the duality is essentially trivial) with a friend, I wondered if this self-duality in dimension 2 was anyhow related to the commutativity of the multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ viewed as a division algebra. Indeed the geometric duality in dimension 1, 2 and 3 preserves the Euler-Poincaré characteristics but exchanging vertices and "$3$-faces" on one hand and edges and "$2$-faces" on the other hand in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ changes the Euler-Poincaré characteristics to its opposite, and it is well known that the quaternions division algebra has a non commutative multiplication. Is it just a coincidence, or does something deeper lie behind this observation ?

Comment: How would you define multiplication in R^d for d other than 2 and 4?

Comment: There is one for $d=8$ and $d=16$, namely for octonions and sedenions. Note also that I don't expect an equivalence here, but rather two different manifestations of an invariance under permutation (the one that permutes $a$ and $b$ in $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ and the one that permutes the "faces" of dimension $n$ and $d-n$).